Ktor - Reading field '_id' failed expected STRING type but found: OBJECT_ID when using @Serializable with MongoDB
Problem
While integrating MongoDB with a Ktor server using @Serializable for data classes, I encountered the following error:
Reading field '_id' failed expected STRING type but found: OBJECT_ID

The issue occurred when the _id field in MongoDB, stored as an ObjectId, was expected to be a String during deserialization. This happened because kotlinx.serialization doesn’t natively support BSON-specific types like ObjectId.

What I Tried

Using @BsonId
Initially, I annotated the _id field in the User data class with @BsonId:
@Serializable
data class User(
    @BsonId val id: ObjectId,
    val googleId: String,
    val email: String,
    val emailVerified: Boolean,
    val givenName: String,
    val familyName: String,
    val profilePicture: String?
)

However, this resulted in deserialization errors because kotlinx.serialization didn’t recognize the ObjectId type.

Custom Serialization Attempts
I tried creating a basic custom serializer but failed to handle BSON and JSON serialization properly. Missing opt-ins for experimental features (ExperimentalSerializationApi) compounded the issue.





Solution
To resolve the issue, I implemented a custom KSerializer specifically for ObjectId that handles both BSON (for MongoDB) and JSON (for REST APIs):
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
object ObjectIdSerializer : KSerializer<ObjectId> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
        PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ObjectId", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ObjectId) {
        when (encoder) {
            is BsonEncoder -> encoder.encodeBsonValue(BsonObjectId(value)) // BSON serialization
            else -> encoder.encodeString(value.toHexString()) // JSON serialization
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ObjectId {
        return when (decoder) {
            is BsonDecoder -> decoder.decodeBsonValue().asObjectId().value // BSON deserialization
            else -> ObjectId(decoder.decodeString()) // JSON deserialization
        }
    }
}

With this serializer, I updated the data class as follows:
@Serializable
data class User(
    @SerialName("_id") // Use this instead of @BsonId
    @Serializable(with = ObjectIdSerializer::class)
    val id: ObjectId? = null, // Nullable to handle optional fields
    val googleId: String, // From `sub`
    val email: String,
    val emailVerified: Boolean,
    val givenName: String,
    val familyName: String,
    val profilePicture: String? = null
)


How It Works

Custom Serialization

BSON Context: When working directly with MongoDB (via the driver), the ObjectId is serialized as a BSON ObjectId type.
JSON Context: For REST APIs, the ObjectId is converted to its string representation (toHexString()).


Annotations

@SerialName("_id"): Maps the _id field in MongoDB to the Kotlin property id.
@Serializable(with = ObjectIdSerializer::class): Specifies the custom serializer for ObjectId.


Error Prevention
This solution ensures that the deserialization process correctly identifies and handles the _id field as an ObjectId instead of mistakenly expecting a String.



Key Takeaways

Conflict Between @BsonId and @Serializable
The @BsonId annotation provided by the MongoDB Kotlin driver doesn’t work seamlessly with @Serializable. Use @SerialName instead.

Custom Serializers for BSON Types
When dealing with BSON-specific types (e.g., ObjectId), a custom KSerializer is required.

Opt-In for Experimental APIs
Don’t forget to add @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class) when using certain serialization features.



What Can Be Improved?

Native Support in kotlinx.serialization
Adding first-class support for BSON types in kotlinx.serialization would streamline MongoDB integrations.

Standard Error Messages
The error message "expected STRING type but found: OBJECT_ID" could be more descriptive to help developers identify serialization mismatches.



Conclusion
By implementing a custom KSerializer and using @SerialName for field mapping, I successfully handled MongoDB's ObjectId type in a @Serializable data class. This approach ensures compatibility between BSON and JSON serialization.

